Easiest way to shoot and kill an enemy?
I would like an easy way to be able to shoot an enemy and eliminate them from the scene this is what i did. is there any other way?
public class SpawnBullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefabBullett;
    public Transform centerBullett; // empty gameObject

    GameManager _gameManager;

    void Start()
    {
        _gameManager = FindObjectOfType<GameManager>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            GameObject bullett= Instantiate(prefabBullett, centerBullett.position, centerBullett.rotation);
            Rigidbody rb = bullett.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
      
      rb.AddForce(centerBullett.forward*10,ForceMode.Impulse);

            Destroy (bullett,2);
        }
    }
}

and than i created a script for destroy the enemy
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Bullett")
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);      //delete yourself
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }
    }


Easiest way to shoot and kill an enemy? - well that’s one way to put it, please don’t take it out of context :)

you may use a raycast between the player and the enemy or do a colision check at every refresh. raycasting is a faster but it will not take bullet time and bullet drop into account in his simple form. colision check may be done with shader computation (looking at intersecting pixels).

Your code looks ok, but why did you put the code to destroy yourself before destroying the bullet? That may cause problems. About shooting it's always better to use raycasts if your bullets speed doesn't matter much.

You are missing the code to check if its an enemy. If bullet is spawned too close to the shooter, the shooter would shoot itself.

Your solution is great, although you might have an issue when trying to destroy the gameobject twice.
I would change this line here:
Destroy(bullett,2);

To this:
StartCoroutine(DestroySelfAfterDelay(bullett, 2));

Then:
private IEnumerator DestroySelfAfterDelay(GameObject target, float delay)
{
    yield return new Waitforseconds(delay);
    
    if(target == null) // check it's not already been destroyed
        return;

    Destroy(target);
}

This will avoid a NullRefrenceExeption.
You could also look into object pooling if you are going to be firing a lot of bullets. But right now that's pretty much the simplest way to do this, if it works then keep it.
